# Building Rcpp package: How to make functions internal

Tags: c++, rcpp, devtools, r-package, roxygen2

I am building an R package using Rcpp the devtools::check() indicates following warning:

```
checking for missing documentation entries ... WARNING
  Undocumented code objects:
    ‘rfun’ ‘cppfun’
  All user-level objects in a package should have documentation entries.
  See chapter ‘Writing R documentation files’ in the ‘Writing R
  Extensions’ manual.
```

'**rfun**' is an R function that I want to make for internal use. '**cppfun**' is a cpp function that I **Rcpp::export** and I also want to make it internal.

My solution: Adding **#' @noRd** on the top of **rfun** codes, adding **#' @noRd** on the top of **//[[Rcpp::export]]** of **cppfun** codes.

These don't work. Guess I am on the wrong track. BTW I use devtools and roxygen2.

Comment: See the Rcpp Attributes vignette, you want an argument inside `Rcpp::export` as for example `// [[Rcpp::export(.rfun)]]`.  There are other ways: just define but don't export.  In essence you are currently fighting mano-a-mano between R (complains), devtools (complains), roxygen (may need a tag) and Rcpp which just merrily hands you your function.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Thank you Dirk. As for the rfun, why `#' @noRd `doesn't work?

Comment: No idea, maybe it does? Search maybe with the `github.com/cran` "organization" that mirrors CRAN to find an example.  I support Rcpp, it works, You have a problem with else (yet related) here.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel I just realize that I could change the exportpattern in namespace file. Hope this will help :)

Comment: The default one implies skipping names with dots, hence my answer. But you are getting closer to what I alluded to four hours ago about the multiple daemons you are currently facing.  And please do not confuse those for Rcpp issues: it's all upstream from us.